# Enable lazy loading in a query

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have set NHibernate to not lazy load for my entities. But sometimes when I do queries I don't want all the children of the children to be loaded. The mapping is set up by Fluent NHibernate.

Is there any way when writing the sql for the query to specify which columns to lazy load?

Answer (score 3):

I believe, you're using the wrong approach. Set all mappings to lazy load, and then in the queries eager load only what you really need. This way you won't kill the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can override all the mappings defined in Fluent Mappings in conventions either in class mappings.
There also are different scenarios where NHibernate does the trick (for instance if you load / get one instance all the properties will be fetched as defined in mapping. If you get a list of items it will not happen unless you use Fetch method explicitly).
So could you provide some more details on your question to give an answer that is more precise?